# display two pairs of words with a loop

Tags: python

I have a first .txt file that contains 5 words each on a line, and another one that contains 100 keywords (each on a line too). I want to print for each word, the whole list of terms. Here's what I did :

```
words = open("./sample_5.txt","r", encoding='utf8')
termes = open("./100_keywords.txt", "r", encoding='utf8')
for w in words:
    for t in termes:
        print (w,t)
```

Trouble is, this does not iterate on w, which means it returns to me the first word with the 100keyword and that's it. I should have a matrice of (5,100) and i get (1,100). Any help?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding the problem. Can you give a sample of the actual and expected output for certain inputs? Maybe on smaller files, like if the first file has 2 words and the second file has 3.

Answer (score 2):

I think this would help.

Here we read the files specified as array of lines (we used `.readlines()` since the items are each on a separate line).
then do a [cartesian product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) between these lines (equivalent to writing nested loop). then just print them.

**Explanation:**

when we deal with files (use `open`) python internally creates a stream ([TextIOBase](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase)) and every time we try read from the buffer, the next call returns from where left off. So unless you close/open the file inside the second loop, or seek to read from beginning, you wont get the already read strings back. In the solution I gave, we only read the files at the beginning once.

```
from itertools import product

words = open("./a.txt","r", encoding='utf8').readlines()
termes = open("./b.txt", "r", encoding='utf8').readlines()

for word, term in product(words, termes):
    print(word.strip(), term.strip())
```

Comment: Can you explain how this answer works, yet the approach that the OP took did not?

Comment: @quamrana I've tried to provide some explanation, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED** per @Brian McCutchon's comment

Since you want to iterate through the second file multiple times,
you want to use a static container like a list,
otherwise, you can only iterate it once:

```py
words = open("./sample_5.txt","r", encoding='utf8')
termes = open("./100_keywords.txt", "r", encoding='utf8').read().splitlines()
for w in words:
    for t in termes:
        print (w,t)
```

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon in the nested for loop: For every w in `words` OP is iterating through the `terms`. So OP is trying to iterate though the second file object, `terms` 5 times.

Comment: You are right, I edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do:

```
with open("./sample_5.txt","r", encoding='utf8') as words, open("./100_keywords.txt", "r", encoding='utf8') as termes:
        a = termes.readlines()
        for w in words:
            for t in a:
                print (w,t.replace('\n',''))
```